# The best way to modify a CollectionType

Tags: ios, swift, collections

I am extending `CollectionType` and want to be able to modify the collection type easily.

You can't do `myCollection[Index] = whatever`

Whats the best way to modify it's contents?

example

```
extension CollectionType {
    func doSomething() -> Self{
        var result = self
        result[self.startIndex] = result[self.endIndex]
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show a (short) self-contained example demonstrating the problem. Perhaps you defined the collection as a *constant* with `let`? Or forget to mark the method as mutating?

Comment: First subclass collectionViewCell. Get the cell of that index at collectionView (cellforrowatindexpath). Then call any method you wrote at cell.

Comment: i said CollectionType, not CollectionView

Comment: A *self-contained example* is a code snippet which I can copy/paste into my Xcode project and reproduce the problem. You do not even provide the exact error message, or tell what theIndexIWantToModify and updatedItem are.

Comment: Does that help you?

Comment: Make it an extension of  `MutableCollectionType` ...